# How to save the value of one form in two fields of the model?

Tags: django

I want the value from the admission form to be saved in the admission and in_stock fields. there is no in_stock form on the form filling page

models.py

```
class Admission(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100,db_index=True)
date = models.DateTimeField()
in_stock = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
admission = models.IntegerField()

def __str__(self):
    return '{}'.format(self.name)
```

forms.py

```
class AdmissionForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Admission
    fields = ['date', 'name', 'admission', 'in_stock']
```

views.py

```
class AdmissionCreate(View):
def get (self, request):
    form = AdmissionForm()
    return render(request, 'inventory/addAdmissions.html', context={'form': form})

def post(self, request):
    form = AdmissionForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect(admission_list)
```

Comment: Could you explain what the error you're encountering is? The fields should be populated once the form has been saved

Comment: the value of one admission form must be saved in two model fields (admission, in_stock)

Comment: The fields are part of one model and the form is connected to that model, there is no mismatch in having one form and two model fields as the form has those fields (you've set that in your forms.py file).

Comment: I need for example: {{form.admission}} = '111', and so that it is saved to the database like this: admission = '111' and in_ stock = '111'
but the in_stock value is not entered on the page.html (
{{form.date}}
{{form.name}}
{{form.admission}}
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood currently, you want to submit a form but have a field value duplicated across to another one, i.e. the admission field would be 111 and upon saving the form in_stock would also be 111. One way to do this would be in the form validation and defining a `clean_fieldname` function.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/

```py
class AdmissionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Admission
        fields = ['date', 'name', 'admission', 'in_stock']

    def clean_in_stock(self):
        return self.cleaned_data['admission']
```

One doubt that I have is that you are requesting `in_stock` in your form which is presumably being rendered in HTML and a value entered when the form is submitted. You may not want to do this and could exclude the field from the form altogether in the form's Meta.